Email is sending sucessfully but we're not receiving it when we are sending it from salesforce
I have a button in LWC component. When I click the button, the LWC form will open. When we filled and submit the form, an email has to be sent, but even though the email is sent successfully in debug logs, no email is received. (I've checked the junk folder.)
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
      public static string sendEmail(String AccountName,String AccountPhone,String AccountAddress,String AccountCity,String AccountState,String AccountZip,String ServiceDelivery,String ServiceNeeded,String AdditionalComments,String RequestedBy,String ServiceDate,String LocationofParts,String CurrentDate,String userName,string threadid,Id caseId){
        String marketEmail='';
        Case caseData = [Select Id, Legacy_Account_Ship_To__c from Case where Id=: caseId LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('legacy is '+caseData);
        if(caseData != null && caseData.Legacy_Account_Ship_To__c != null){
          list < Market_Configuration__mdt > marketConfigList = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel, DeveloperName,Fulfiller_Id__c,Service_Delivery_Distro__c FROM Market_Configuration__mdt where Fulfiller_Id__c=:caseData.Legacy_Account_Ship_To__c and MasterLabel !='ASHCOMM' and MasterLabel !='Blank'];
          if(!marketConfigList.isEmpty()){
            marketEmail =  marketConfigList[0].Service_Delivery_Distro__c;
            System.debug('Service Delivery Distro: ' + marketConfigList[0].Service_Delivery_Distro__c);
          }
        }

         List<String> recordIdList = ServiceDelivery.split(',');
         List<ProductLineItem__c> productLineItems = [SELECT Item_SKU__c,Sales_Order_Number__c FROM ProductLineItem__c WHERE Id IN :recordIdList];

         System.debug('the product line items are '+productLineItems);
        System.debug('ServiceNeeded '+ ServiceNeeded );
        System.debug('AdditionalComments '+ AdditionalComments);
        System.debug('RequestedBy ' + RequestedBy);
        System.debug('ServiceDate ' + ServiceDate );
        System.debug('LocationofParts '  + LocationofParts);
        System.debug('CurrentDate ' + CurrentDate);
        System.debug('userName ' + userName);
       String productLineItemsHTML = '';
       for(ProductLineItem__c item : productLineItems) {
        productLineItemsHTML += '<tr>' +
                                 '<td style="text-align: center;">' + item.Item_SKU__c + '</td>' +
                                 '<td style="text-align: center;">' + item.Sales_Order_Number__c + '</td>' +
                               '</tr>';
    }

String messageBody =
    '<html><head><title>Service Delivery</title></head>' +
    '<style>' +
    '  .highlighted-heading { font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffbf00;text-align: center;}' +
    '  .mytable, .mytable1 { width: 100%; }' +
    '  .mytable th, .mytable td, .mytable1 th, .mytable1 td {padding: 5px; }' +
    '  .thead { background-color: #f2f2f2; }' +
    '  .checkbox-cell { display: flex; align-items: center; }' +
    '  .small-checkbox { margin-right: 8px; }' +
    '  .from { font-weight: bold; background-color: #ffbf00;}' +
    '</style>' +
    '<body>'  +
    '    <div>' +
    '      <header>' +
    '        <h2 class="highlighted-heading">Service Delivery</h2>' +
    '      </header>' +
    '      <div>' +
    '        <table class="mytable">' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td class="from">From:</td>' +
    '            <td class="value">Brandon Warehouse</td>' +
    '            <td class="from">Customer\'s Name:</td>' +
    '            <td class="value">' + AccountNameWithCommas + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td></td>' +
    '            <td>2998 Broadway Center Blvd</td>' +
    '            <td class="from">Address:</td>' +
    '            <td class="value">' + AccountAddress + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td></td>' +
    '            <td class="value">Brandon, FL 33510</td>' +
    '            <td></td>' +
    '            <td class="value">' + AccountCity + ', ' + AccountState + ' ' + AccountZip + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td></td>' +
    '            <td></td>' +
    '            <td class="from">Phone Number:</td>' +
    '            <td class="value1">' + AccountPhone + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '        </table>' +
    '        <table class="mytable1">' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <th class="thead" style="background-color: #ffbf00;">Item Number</th>' +
    '            <th class="thead" style="background-color: #ffbf00;">Sale Order</th>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    productLineItemsHTML +
    '        </table>' +
    '        <table class="mytable1">' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <th class="thead" style="background-color: #ffbf00;">Service Needed</th>' +
    '            <th class="thead" style="background-color: #ffbf00;">Additional Comments</th>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td style="text-align: center;">' +
    '              <textarea name="serviceNeeded" readonly="true" rows="4" cols="50">' + ServiceNeeded + '</textarea>' +
    '            </td>' +
    '            <td style="text-align: center;">' +
    '              <textarea name="additionalComments" readonly="true" rows="4" cols="50" style="border: none; outline: none;">' + AdditionalComments + '</textarea>' +
    '            </td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '        </table>' +
    '        <table class="mytable">' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td class="from">Requested By:</td>' +
    '            <td class="value">' + userName + '</td>' +
    '            <td class="from">Date:</td>' +
    '            <td>' + currentDate + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '          <tr>' +
    '            <td class="from">Service Date:</td>' +
    '            <td>' + ServiceDate + '</td>' +
    '            <td class="from">Location of parts:</td>' +
    '            <td>' + LocationofParts + '</td>' +
    '          </tr>' +
    '        </table>' +
    '      </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </section>' +
    '<div>' + threadid + '</div>'+
    '</body>' +
    '</html>';

    if(marketEmail == ''){
      return 'No market email found for the given case.';
    }

        /*Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
          message.toAddresses = new String[] {marketEmail}; 
         message.subject = 'Service Delivery Request';
         message.HtmlBody = messageBody;
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
          Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);*/
          OrgWideEmailAddress owea = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
          try {
              owea = [SELECT Id,DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName = '**************'];
          } catch(Exception e) {
          }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
          message.toAddresses = new String[] {marketEmail}; 
          message.subject = ' Service Delivery Request';
          message.HtmlBody = messageBody;
          message.setSaveAsActivity(true);
          message.setWhatId(caseId);
          if(owea != null){
              System.debug('owea is not null');
              message.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.Id);
          }
          
          Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
          Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
          String messageOutput;
          String emailAddress = message.toAddresses != null && message.toAddresses.size() > 0 ? message.toAddresses[0] : 'unknown';
          System.debug(emailAddress);
          for(Messaging.SendEmailResult res:results){
              if(res.isSuccess()){
                 messageOutput = 'Email sent successfully';
                System.debug('Email sent successfully '+emailAddress);
                return messageOutput;
              }else{
                   messageOutput = 'Email Sent Failed';
                  System.debug('Email Sent Failed');
                  return messageOutput + '. Market Email: ' + marketEmail;
                }
              }
              return 'Unknown error';
      }


Setup -> Email Logs. Request a log and check it. A healthy send will have 2 lines, with R and D (don't remember all meanings but there's a help article linked on the page). Do you send straight from Salesforce or via your company's email relay?

If your code sends the email and doesn't get an error, it's not a programming question anymore, but an email delivery question, and hence off-topic here. That said, it can take a few days until a mail server bounces an email as undeliverable, so maybe you need to wait. (You did put in a valid sender / return address, right?) If you're hosting your own mail server, check the logs. If you are Salesforce email classes, you could check on [salesforce.se].

If it appears that email is send in the debug log, email will be send out. Do you have email deliverability set to 'All Email'? Your code looks fine -https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-50yKc-n5j1PduYw14
